# How to hide persistant navigation bar in flutter on specific screens?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, material-design

I am using a package for persistance navigation bar in flutter. [package](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar). it tried to hide it using getx. like when I navigate to dashboard i call getx fucntion to set the nav to true and when I reach to login screen i set itt to false. but it is not working. I have seen many people have faced this problem but no one gave the correct solution to it.

here is My code.

homepage screen

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:newmart/Order/order.dart';
import 'package:newmart/Screens/dashboard.dart';
import 'package:newmart/Recharge/recharge.dart';
import 'package:newmart/Company/support.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:newmart/mpin/set_mpin.dart';
import 'package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar/persistent_tab_view.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:newmart/getxcontrollers/navController.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key, required this.mobileNumber});
  final String mobileNumber;
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // String mb = "";
  // late PersistentTabController _controller;
 

  final NavigationBarController _navigationBarController =
      Get.put(NavigationBarController());

  List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
    return [
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.home),
        title: ("Home"),
        activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeGreen,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
     ...rest
    ];
  }

  final controler = PersistentTabController();
  List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
    return [
      const Dashboard(),
      const Order(),
      const SetMpin(),
      const Recharge(),
      const Support(),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PersistentTabView(
      context,
      screens: _buildScreens(),
      hideNavigationBar: _navigationBarController.showNavigationBar.value,
      controller: controler,
      items: _navBarsItems(),
      decoration: NavBarDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1)),
      navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style1,
    );
  }
}
```

controoller

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class NavigationBarController extends GetxController {
  var showNavigationBar = true.obs;

  void toggleNavigationBar(bool value) {
    showNavigationBar.value = value;
  }
}
```

login Page

```
 final NavigationBarController _navigationBarController =
      Get.put(NavigationBarController());
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getCurrentPosition();
    _navigationBarController.showNavigationBar.value = false;
    setState(() {});
  }
rest code...//
```

How can i fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have used `NavigationBarController` only to hide/show bottom navigation bar. using your code bottom bar not appear on home screen as well. By commenting `hideNavigationBar: _navigationBarController.showNavigationBar.value,` it's working.

You can use `withNavBar: false` when redirect to login screen. It's working for me.

```
PersistentNavBarNavigator.pushNewScreen(
    context,
    screen: LoginScreen(),
    withNavBar: false, // OPTIONAL VALUE. True by default.
    pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
);
```